# Openfire3.6.3 unable to connect to yahoo gateways

Tags: openfire, gateway, chatbot, yahoo-messenger

I am newbie as far as openfire is concerned.

I want every user whether its on gtalk, yahoo, MSN to contact to my server but right now only gtalk users are able to connect and see presence connected. but yahoo users are able to add me as buddy but presence goes offline always.

I have checked the connection in gateways tab  it shows connection success.

Connect to host: scs.msg.yahoo.com
Connect to port: 5050

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: i have the same problem. i can register in yahoo network however when i try to logon nothing happens.

Comment: this question should be moved to serverfault.com